# computed column on a DataTable involving some operation with an external value

Tags: c#, datatable

Presenting here the problem and a solution to a common scenario you might encounter while using datatable.

Generating a computed column is easy. Say you need a column called `TotalAmount`, which doesn't exist in your datatable yet. Its value is computed by the product of two fields, say, `UnitPrice` and `Quantity`. We write it as follows:

```
var TotalAmountCol = new DataColumn("TotalAmount", 
    typeof(double), "UnitPrice * Quantity");
dt.Columns.Add(TotalAmountCol);
```

So this will enable you to compute your total expenses. So now that you have the total expense, and individual TotalAmounts, how to calculate how much percentage of the expenses is the TotalAmount.

Clearly this involves summing and dividing that individual total amounts by that sum. How do we do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we compute the sum:

```
var sum = dt.Compute("Sum(TotalAmount)", string.Empty);
```

Notice that `dt.Compute()` [returns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) an object.

We now make the new column as follows:

```
var PercentAmountCol = new DataColumn("PercentAmount",
    typeof(double), 
    "TotalAmount / " + sum.ToString()");
dt.Columns.Add(PercentAmountCol);
```

Simple! Just saved you from doing LINQ.

POC: http://dotnetpad.net/ViewPaste/hRsQhJe6AU2g2GEGaioNBA

Comment: yep it will. Added an example